# Java paintComponent running but not showing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

so I just want to paint a square in a random part of the screen as a custon `JComponent`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if( this.good ){
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    }
    else{
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    }
    g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    System.out.println("painting");
}
```

here is the method that calls painting via `repaint()`

```
private void stateChange(){
        
    double rand = Math.random();
        
    if (rand < 0.5){
        this.good = !this.good;
    }
    setLocation(this.x,this.y);
    repaint();
}
```

`this.x` and `this.y` are constantly changing, but I know that works. When I run my code, it prints `"painting"` where it should, **but nothing is showing up**. Am I doing something wrong?

## extra code:

here is what I put for trying to get it to show up:

```
\\in JComponent constructore
setOpaque(true);
setVisible(true);
setSize(this.w,this.h);
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, based on the example code you've provided, is the fact that you are actually painting out side of the bounds of viewable space of the component.

When painting, the top, left corner of the `Graphics` context is `0x0`, Swing has already translated the `Graphics` context based on the position of the component, so...

```
g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
```

Is actually (possibly) painting beyond the viewable area of the component.  For example, if the `x` position is `10` and `y` is `10`, but height and width is only `10`, `10`, you are painting at position `10x10`, which would be beyond the viewable space of the component, instead, you should try something like...

```
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
```

Or, based on your example code,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if( this.good ){
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    }
    else{
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    }
    super.paintComponent(g2d);
}
```

Instead....

Answer (score 3):

My guess: you have a while (true) loop that ties up the Swing event thread, so while you are changing state, the GUI can't repaint itself to show it happening. Either that or your JComponent's size is very small, too small to show the image.

For an answer that's more than a guess, you'll need to ask a more complete question with pertinent code.

Note that your `paintComponent(...)` method override is missing its call to the super's method.

Note: you can test the JComponent's size by adding a getSize() method in your paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);  // **** don't forget this.
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if( this.good ){
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    }
    else{
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    }
    g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);

    // TODO: ***** delete this lines
    System.out.println("painting");
    System.out.println(getSize());  // **** add this***
}
```

Note: you should **not** call `setSize(...)` on your component. It is usually misleading as it's often ignored by the layout managers.

Comment: I have no loops, and the size is 50 by 50

Comment: @RyanSaxe: see edits, please add more relevant information to make your question complete.

Comment: how come the size is 1,1 when `this.w` and `this.h` are both 50?

Comment: you were right about the size being too small, but it makes no sense given that I set the size to be 50,50

Comment: @RyanSaxe: If you need it to show an image, then override getPreferredSize() and calculate a decent Dimension for it to return.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42292/discussion-between-ryan-saxe-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)